# OkHttp doesn't reuse HTTPS/HTTP2 connections

Tags: java, android, networking, okhttp, http2

Each time I make a new request, a new connection is open.
There isn't any connection reuse whatsoever.
What am I doing wrong?

I am using the latest OkHttp package (3.11.0).
My server is supporting HTTP/2. The request URLs are all HTTPS.

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    try {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        mJSONstring = response.body().string();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: maybe it's because I am instantiating a new client each time?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason: I was instantiating a new client each time.

If you want to reuse connections, you should use the same client instance for all the calls.